# Perl - assigning hashes - why assigned variable is changed?

Tags: perl, hash, variable-assignment

I have the following problem:
I have a perl program which is extracting csv files, reads them and outputing result.
The information about the csv structure is in XML files, provided in the archives mentioned above.
In the old version of the program i have read those XML files for each line of the CSV file and everithing worked fine:

```
...;
foreach $b (@gz_files) 
{
  if ( index($b, 'condition1') >= 0
    || index($b, 'condition2') >= 0 
    || index($b, 'condition3') >= 0 )
  {
    $lt = localtime;
    open (my $outputfile, '>>'.'/path_to_output/'.$dir_file.'.tmp')
      || die print $lfh "$lt -     /path_to_output/$dir_file\.tmp - $!\n";
    if ($b ne "")
    {
      # this is the procedure, which reads xml_files
      %cv_tmp = eventstype::initialize($complex_xml_path, $rating_input_xml_path);
      @EXPORT=qw(%cv_tmp);
...;
```

This code adds the structure from XML files into %cv_tmp variable.
After that foreach row in CSV file I'am assigning the value of %cv_tmp to %complex_vals which is manipulated further.

```
...
%complex_vals=%mainfile::cv_tmp;
...
```

But after this manipulation i notice that %cv_tmp has changed - which is strange because this is the right-side of the assignment.
I do not want to change the %cv_tmp on each CSV row.
Sorry for the bad description but I am absolutely novice.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate the problem. Please provide the smallest amount of runnable code that recreates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps have something like

```
my %h1;
$h1{foo}{bar} = 123;

my %h2 = %h1;
$h2{foo}{bar} = 456;

print "$h1{foo}{bar}\n";  # 456
```

If so, you're not changing `%h1` or `%h2`; you're changing the (anonymous) hash referenced by both `$h1{foo}` and `$h2{foo}`. You need to copy the referenced hash (not the reference to the hash) to solve this problem.

```
use Storable qw( dclone );

my %h1;
$h1{foo}{bar} = 123;

my %h2 = %{ dclone(\%h1) };
$h2{foo}{bar} = 456;

print "$h1{foo}{bar}\n";  # 123
```

Comment: Thank you very much I think that this solved my problem, but would you be so kind to explain why using dclone is needed. And should I use this every time when I'm assigning hash to hash?
Best regards,
Georgi

Comment: In this particular case there are two hash variables, but in the program I'm using other hash assignments which are for different purpose and I don't see any problems whith them (still). But never mind, I just asked in theory.
Thank you once again, I've tried to rise the counter, but I have raiting less than 15 :)

Comment: No, I said there are three hash variables. %h1, which is copied into %h2, and %{ $h1{foo} }, which is never copied. You only need `dclone` if you to copy this third hash.